# Repartition During Mint Install, Long Time Unresponsive

Tags: linux-mint, system-installation

I am running Windows 10, loading Linux mint from a USB and attempting to repartition my (240GB) hard drive to leave 150 GB for Windows (it was previously using ~100GB. I pressed "continue" and had a short hang (~2 mins), then the screen went black. After that, several lines of error messages flashed up three times, approx. 10 minutes apart, but nothing that I could connect to the partition process. No change observed for 7 hours (I left it running overnight). Have I made a mistake, or might this just be getting a long time? 
[image: top half of screen]
[image: bottom half of screen]
NB: The fan is still going so I suspect it's doing *something*, but I don't know what.

Comment: in this case you apparently have a problem with your motherboard and CPU. You CPU is too high on temperature and apparently linux have some trouble handling your hardware configuration. What is your computer ? In my opinion when you've reach such a bad point you could only try to reboot but if the resize process has started but not finish your computer will not boot properly.

Comment: It's a Thinkpad E530 Edge, I can't think why there would be a problem with the hardware as I've never come across a problem before, and it's quite fast compared to other laptops I've used. Will try this and get back later.